# Automated URL checking from a MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql, http-status-code-404

Okay, I have a list of URLs in a MySQL table. I want the script to automatically check each link in the table for 404, and afterward I want it to store whether the URL was 404'd or not, as well as store a time for last checked.

Is this even possible to do automatically, even if no one runs the script? ie, no one visits the page for a few days, but even with no one visiting the page, it automatically ran the test.

If its possible, how could I go about making a button to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use CURL, `file_get_contents($url);` will return false if the request fails (any other HTTP code other than 2xx), which might be more useful for what you're trying to do, an example:

```
function urlExists($url)
{
    return (bool) @file_get_contents($url);
}
```

Will return true if the URL returns useful content, false otherwise.

---

**EDIT**: Here is a faster way (it only requests the headers) and **the first byte** instead of the whole page:

```
function urlExists($url)
{
    return (bool) @file_get_contents($url, false, null, 0, 1);
}

urlExists('https://stackoverflow.com/iDontExist'); // false
```

---

However, in combination with [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719098/using-php-to-determine-if-a-remote-file-has-been-replaced) it may be wiser to use something like this:

```
function url($url)
{
    return @file_get_contents($url);
}

$content = url('https://stackoverflow.com/');

// request has failed (404, 5xx, etc...)
if ($content === false)
{
    // delete or store as "failed" in the DB
}

// request was successful
else
{
    $hash = md5($content); // md5() should be enough but you can also use sha1()

    // store $hash in the DB to keep track of changes
}
```

Or if you're using PHP 5.1+ you only have to do:

```
$hash = @md5_file($url);
```

`$hash` will be false when the URL fails to load, otherwise it will return the MD5 hash of the contents.

Graciously [stolen from @Jamie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719098/using-php-to-determine-if-a-remote-file-has-been-replaced/2719129#2719129). =)

This way you only have to make one request instead of two. =)

Comment: Sorry for the late late response. Been a bit busy. Thanks a lot, @md5_file(); is great. Can you tell me though, what is the '@' in front of the function for?

Comment: Rob: Is to avoid the function for throwing errors if the url fails to load.

Comment: So if I put that in my curl_multi_exec (as in @curl_multi_exec();), it will run all the urls regardless of errors? (See my open question for more information)

Comment: @Rob: The `@` operator only suppresses errors for being thrown, nothing more. Regarding your other question, you're using curl_multi wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You would use a cron job to do this. Using a cron job you pick when the script is run e.g. every hour, every 6 hours, etc...

To check 404 you can loop through the urls and use [get_headers](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) updating a status row each time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `curl`:

```
// $url <= The URL from your database
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
if(curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 404) 
{
  // Save in database.
}
curl_close($curl);
```

If you are running on a shared hosting server, look for the possibility of setting up timed actions (cron jobs). Some hosting services have it, some don't.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using `curl` as well, but make `HEAD` request instead of `GET`:

```
<?php
function check_url($url) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1); // get the header
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); // and *only* get the header
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); // get the response as a string from curl_exec(), rather than echoing it
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1); // don't use a cached version of the url
    if (!curl_exec($c)) { return false; }

    $httpcode = curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    return $httpcode;
}
?>
```

Snipplet taken from [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php#82300).

Recurring execution can be achieved by *nix cron command.