# Using PHP to determine if a remote file has been replaced?

Tags: php

I have a MySQL database with some URLs in it. One URL per row. Each URL has my script on it. What I am wanting to do, is check if the file is still there via a PHP script. Not check if it 404'd, but rather check if it has been modified or replaced. Is this possible? If so, how would it be accomplished?

I was thinking making the remote file echo some string, and having the local file check the page for that string, but that seems a little inefficient and sloppy.

**EDIT:** The remote files don't output any data to the remote users, they trigger internal scripts, so remote users would only see a white page. (The checking script would only see this as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Bulletproof Way

1. Fetch the URL contents.
2. Compute the `MD5()` or `SHA1()` hash.
3. Fetch the URL again and check if the hash has changed.

There are other ways (such as the `Last-Modified` HTTP header), but they don't work with all servers.

Comment: Alright, sounds great. How could I compute the the MD5? Just get the contents using curl and then md5($contents)? Will this work even if there's no output from that remote file? (At least none visible to remote users)

Comment: @Rob: See my answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719012/automated-url-checking-from-a-mysql-table/2719162#2719162) on your other question, it addresses specifically that issue. =)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can ask to the file to send his md5 under certain conditions, for example:

```
if($_GET['md5hash']==true)
{ 
  echo md5($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
}
```

You can easily understand if your script is changed by receiving his md5 or receiving something different by his md5, but i don't know what is the score for you.

Answer (score 1):

just use

```
md5_file('http://path.to/file');
```

and store the hash for checking later

Answer (score 0):

if the urls are local files you can use [filemtime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filemtime.php) on each file and check the time against the modifiedtime row in the table.

Comment: They aren't local. Sorry, you probably typed this up before I edited my question. I made a typo in the title. I accidentally put local instead of remote

Answer (score 0):

You may also be able to use [`stat`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stat.php) on a remote file and check the `mtime` record.